# Question regarding Frame and Frame Rate

Tags: rendering, animation, edit-mode, keyframes, frame-rate

Good day.

If rendering at 30 fps from 0 frame to 300 frame, will it render 10 seconds worth of animation or would it be 10:01 seconds? Thanks.

Comment: That's 301 frames @ 1/30 of a second each : 10.0333 seconds

Comment: I see, the thing is i'm timing my scene to a specific music or sound. Regarding the mp3 file, the music starts at 0.. so 0 is counted as 1 second then, eh?

Comment: If the mp3 duration is measured in time, then its 0s marks the _beginning_ of frame 1, and its 10s marks the _end_ of frame 300. Hence the confusion? Think fence-posts and the gaps between them. Blender, by default, considers frame 1 to go from 0s > 1/30s, but you could make that frame 0, if you liked. Just remember that would be 0 > 299, with the time-points marking the _beginning_ of each frame.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that one, cheers. It's just I noticed that when I play the music via vlc or whatever, the music starts at 0s. and I'm timing my scenes based on the seconds of the music with respect to blender video editor. So if I count 1 second on the mp3 as 1 second on blender, then I'm off by 1 second, cuz the music starts at 0s. That's why I needed clarification on blender's start frame and end frame to match the music.